# Подскажите библиотеку для перевода аудио в текст

Tags: распознавание-речи

Необходимо транскрибировать аудиофайл с начиткой в текст. 
Было бы хорошо использовать библиотеку на серверном языке программирования с записью результата в базу данных.

**Ожидаемый результат:**
Библиотека (или API) на любом языке программирования, где на вход подаётся аудиофайл, а на выходе выводит текст (искажения допускаются, чтоб хотя бы половина слов была разобрана)

**Что я нагуглил:**
cloud.google.com/speech - но там есть ограничения на количество текста)
https://speechpad.ru/ - та же тема.
В вышеуказанных сервисах достаточно высокое качество распознавания текста, это соизмеряется платой за это)
Меня же интересуют бесплатные варианты, не гонюсь за качеством.

*Такого рода библиотека нужна мне для одного экспериментального проекта)*

Comment: Есть хороший профессиональный форум http://forum.sources.ru/index.php?s=46ec3ae4366df7df0360955742b882e1&showforum=35. Я для этих целей использовал HTK, но это было давно. Лучше спросить там.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот например обертка на Python для библиотеки  [CMU Sphinx-4](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialsphinx4/) 
https://github.com/kelvinguu/simple-speech-recognition
Судя по описанию подходит под ваши требования.

Answer (score 1):

Для распознавания можно использовать библиотеку [vosk-api](https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api). Устанавливается просто - `pip install vosk`.

Русскую модель можно скачать [тут](https://github.com/alphacep/kaldi-android-demo/releases/download/2020-01/alphacep-model-android-ru-0.3.tar.gz).

Примерно вот так выглядит код:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from vosk import Model, KaldiRecognizer
import sys
import os
import wave

if not os.path.exists("model-en"):
    print ("Please download the model from https://github.com/alphacep/kaldi-android-demo/releases and unpack as 'model-en' in the current folder.")
    exit (1)

wf = wave.open(sys.argv[1], "rb")
if wf.getnchannels() != 1 or wf.getsampwidth() != 2 or wf.getcomptype() != "NONE":
    print ("Audio file must be WAV format mono PCM.")
    exit (1)

model = Model("model-en")
rec = KaldiRecognizer(model, wf.getframerate())

while True:
    data = wf.readframes(1000)
    if len(data) == 0:
        break
    if rec.AcceptWaveform(data):
        print(rec.Result())
    else:
        print(rec.PartialResult())

print(rec.FinalResult())
```

Есть поддержка Java и CSharp.